# Create new dataframe in pyspark with column names and its associated values in other column using spark/pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have a dataset like below

[image]

and i would like to create a dataframe using above dataset like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you need stack your dataframe, group by `var_name` and apply `collect_list`

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


expr_columns = ', '.join(map(lambda col: '"{col}", {col}'.format(col=col), df.columns))
expr = "stack(2, {columns}) as (var_name, values)".format(columns=expr_columns)

df_stack = df.selectExpr(expr)
df_final = df_stack.groupBy("var_name").agg(f.collect_list(f.col("values")))
```

Comment: Hi Kafels, I appreciate your efforts, how can i make the stack values dynamic rather then static ? the solution should work for any dataset.

Comment: Hi Kafels, tried the above code on other dataset, but it is trowing error at df_stack  pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'stack(2, 'age', `age`, 'job', `job`, 'marital', `marital`, 'education', `education`, 'default', `default`, 'balance', `balance`, 'housing', `housing`, 'loan', `loan`, 'contact', `contact`, 'day', `day`, 'month', `month`, 'duration', `duration`, 'campaign', `campaign`, 'pdays', `pdays`, 'previous', `previous`, 'poutcome', `poutcome`, 'y', `y`)' due to data type mismatch: Argument 2 (bigint) != Argument 19 (string); line 1 pos 0;

Comment: All columns must have the same data type. Cast them to String and apply stack